# Text-based note taking applicationg with solid math support and good organization

Tags: linux, note-taking, math, latex

I am looking for something like Boostnote. However, it seems that Boostnote is not able to handle very large collections of notes. It also has some interface quirks (it scrolls up and down a bit randomly).

In any case, I am looking for alternative software, or alternative setups to handle a large collection of notes about mathematics. It should run on linux and offline. It should be text-based, so that I can git track the base files efficiently.

Can someone suggest a (simple) workflow?

Answer (score 2):

The closest matches are [Laverna](https://laverna.cc/) (MathJax support, offline storage) and [Cherrytree](https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/). Both works on Linux.

Comment: Do you know if these software scale well with large number of notes?